# Azure RBAC Can't create clusterroles

Tags: azure, azure-aks, rbac

I have an AKS cluster with azure rbac and AAD enabled. I'm trying to create a custom role with min permissions in order to be able to create clusterroles, but I can't get it to work without setting `Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/clusterroles/escalate/action` in the custom role. What is the reason for what / what other rights should I use, so i won't have to use `escalate`.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Kubernetes Restrictions on role creation or update](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#restrictions-on-role-creation-or-update):

You can only create/update a role if at least one of the following things is true:

1. You already have all the permissions contained in the role, at the same scope as the object being modified (cluster-wide for a ClusterRole, within the same namespace or cluster-wide for a Role).
2. You are granted explicit permission to perform the `escalate` verb on the `roles` or `clusterroles` resource in the `rbac.authorization.k8s.io` API group.

For example, if `user-1` does not have the ability to list Secrets cluster-wide, they cannot create a ClusterRole containing that permission. To allow a user to create/update roles:

1. Grant them a role that allows them to create/update Role or ClusterRole objects, as desired.
2. Grant them permission to include specific permissions in the roles they create/update:

   - implicitly, by giving them those permissions (if they attempt to create or modify a Role or ClusterRole with permissions they themselves have not been granted, the API request will be forbidden)
   - or explicitly allow specifying any permission in a `Role` or `ClusterRole` by giving them permission to perform the `escalate` verb on `roles` or `clusterroles` resources in the `rbac.authorization.k8s.io` API group

---

`Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/rbac.authorization.k8s.io/clusterroles/escalate/action` grants explicit permission to perform the `escalate` verb on the `clusterroles` resource in the `rbac.authorization.k8s.io` API group. [[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/resource-provider-operations#microsoftcontainerservice)]